# Button custom attributes for windows forms

Tags: winforms, custom-attributes

I need to add a secondary Id or even some custom text to controls like Button, Textbox, ListBox etc., so that i can later use it for programmatic purposes and should not be displayed to user.

I can do this in ASP.net using Attributes property for almost any control, but when I checked with windows forms I found it doesn’t have this property, can I find any other alternatives in windows forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Control.Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property for this.

```
myButton.Tag = whatever;
myTextBox.Tag = whatever;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Control.Tag` property. Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

"A common use for the Tag property is to store data that is closely associated with the control."

This sounds like what you're after.